# Monotonicity of this function

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers and $f(x)= \frac{a^x}{b^x+c^x}+\frac{b^x}{a^x+c^x}+\frac{c^x}{a^x+b^x}$. Prove that $f$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$.

Before finding a solution calculating $f(y)-f(x)$, which I tried but couldn't, please also tell me if the problem could be done with derivatives.

Comment: You can certainly compute the derivative, but I suspect it will be painful. At least, by hand.

Comment: Since you tagged with calculus, have you tried differentiating it? If so, what can you say about $f'$?

Comment: Solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381486/a-property-of-nesbitts-inequality?noredirect=1) combined with [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1538753p9296332). Results obtained by using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/

Comment: FWIW If you're familiar with smoothing and Jensens, this 3-variable inequality falls to the 3-variable Jensen's smoothing. I've added a solution in the linked problem.

Comment: Thanks for the searching site and the solution!! I tried differentiating but I didn't see the grouping.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Just a precision, when you reference "the linked problem" is it among the two links I gave ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes. It's the MSE one (and also shows up on the right).

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thank you!